# get a phone number's international prefix from a country code in python

Tags: python, internationalization, phone-number

Is it possible to use [python-phonenumbers](https://github.com/daviddrysdale/python-phonenumbers) or another python lib to get a country calling code from a two letter country code ([ISO 3166-1 alpha-2](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_3166-1_alpha-2))?

The examples in the `phonenumbers` lib focus on extracting a country code from a number, but I'd like to do the opposite, something like:

`"US" -> "1"`
`"GB" -> "44"`
`"CL" -> "56"`

Comment: You could look to create a dictionary by parsing the table on the folllowing page although you would have to slice the first two characters from the country letter code column - https://countrycode.org/

Comment: If you look at __Example Usage__ on the following page: [link](https://github.com/daviddrysdale/python-phonenumbers) you can see some examples with parse and country code that gives the phone number

Comment: That's not really a programming question. It's a resource question. You can parse Wikipedia http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_country_calling_codes http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_3166-1_alpha-2

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I don't know of any python lib for this, but [here](http://www.andrewpatton.com/countrylist.csv)'s a csv with all ISO 3166-1 alpha-2 codes and their number prefixes, it should be trivial to look it up from there:

```
import csv

country_to_prefix = {}

with open("countrylist.csv") as csvfile:
    reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
    for row in reader:
        country_to_prefix[row["ISO 3166-1 2 Letter Code"]] = row["ITU-T Telephone Code"]

print country_to_prefix["US"] # +1
print country_to_prefix["GB"] # +44
print country_to_prefix["CL"] # +56
```

**edit:** The above link has gone down, but I've found a [repository with that data (and more)](https://github.com/mledoze/countries) on Github.

Comment: That link doesn't work anymore, because the domain can no longer be resolved.

Comment: @Anthon Thanks for the heads-up, I added a link to a new source (but didn't update the code yet)

Answer (score 8):

using the lib.

```
In [1]: from phonenumbers import COUNTRY_CODE_TO_REGION_CODE

In [2]: COUNTRY_CODE_TO_REGION_CODE
Out[2]: 
{1: ('US',
     'AG',
     'AI',

....
 7: ('RU', 'KZ'),
 20: ('EG',),
 27: ('ZA',),
 30: ('GR',),
 31: ('NL',),
 32: ('BE',),
 33: ('FR',),
 34: ('ES',),
 36: ('HU',),
 39: ('IT', 'VA'),
 40: ('RO',),
 ... snip.
```

Eventually :

```
from phonenumbers import COUNTRY_CODE_TO_REGION_CODE, REGION_CODE_FOR_NON_GEO_ENTITY
REGION_CODE_TO_COUNTRY_CODE = {}

for country_code, region_codes in COUNTRY_CODE_TO_REGION_CODE.items():
    for region_code in region_codes:
        if region_code == REGION_CODE_FOR_NON_GEO_ENTITY:
            continue
        if region_code in REGION_CODE_TO_COUNTRY_CODE:
            raise ValueError("%r is already in the country code list" % region_code)
        REGION_CODE_TO_COUNTRY_CODE[region_code] = str(country_code)
```

The following function will give you the calling code from a provided iso code:

```
def get_calling_code(iso):
  for code, isos in COUNTRY_CODE_TO_REGION_CODE.items():
    if iso.upper() in isos:
        return code
  return None
```

Which gives you:

```
get_calling_code('US')
>> 1
get_calling_code('GB')
>> 44
```

Answer (score 6):

The `phonenumbers` library actually has (as of version 8.10.5 at least) a `country_code_for_region()` function :

```
>>> import phonenumbers
>>> phonenumbers.country_code_for_region("GB")
44
```

Answer (score 0):

Using [python-phonenumbers](https://github.com/daviddrysdale/python-phonenumbers) you can exploit the *COUNTRY_CODE_TO_REGION_CODE* map, it is a dict having international calling codes (int) as key and country codes (str) as values. You just reverse the dict and the work is done.

Here an example (very similar to the answer of [toast38coza](https://stackoverflow.com/users/243806/toast38coza) and [cgte](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7154688/cgte)):

```
REGION_CODE_TO_COUNTRY_CODE = {}
for k, vs in phonenumbers.COUNTRY_CODE_TO_REGION_CODE.items(): # prefix -> country code: 39 -> 'IT'
    for v in vs:   #because a prefix could belong to more countries
       REGION_CODE_TO_COUNTRY_CODE[v] = k # country code-> prefix : 'IT' -> 39# now you have your reversed map

print( 'Italy country prefix: +'+ str( REGION_CODE_TO_COUNTRY_CODE['IT'] ) )
```

Hope it will help