# Convert language to country code with Python

Tags: python

Is it possible to identify the **country code number** by **language**?

It would look something like this:

```
>>> lang = 'en'
>>> print(lang.country_code)
>>> '+1'
```

I searched the `phonenumbers` and `pycountry` libs, but I couldn't find anything like that.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29758553/get-a-phone-numbers-international-prefix-from-a-country-code-in-python

Comment: In this case it's country x code, in mine it's language x code. If `en-US` exists, I only need `en`.

Comment: `en` is ambigous. English is spoke in England, USA, Canada, etc.

Comment: Correct, an idea is just to resolve this ambiguity. The same happens with `pt` (Portuguese), it can be `pt-BR` or `pt-PT`. So, whatever the data structure, you only need one way to make this equivalence, which can be in a dictionary, for example.

Answer (score 2):

I found a JSON containing the requirements of your question, you'll just have to write some code to get the right values from it.

[link](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/Goles/3196253/raw/9ca4e7e62ea5ad935bb3580dc0a07d9df033b451/CountryCodes.json)

Answer (score 0):

You can create a dictionary here with country code like dict ={
"country1": 1234,
"country2": 234,
"country3": 1964
}
and then wherever you want to use it, you can run loop to print the key value using key.